# DataTables jquery identifying row ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using DataTables and capturing am img click on either edit or delete icon's.  My problem is, I need to capture the row ID as well.. I tried putting the row ID in the href tag but npt able to extract it..

The current code is

```
 $('#datatable tbody tr a.delete img').live( 'click', function (e) {
 var rowID = $('a').attr('href');
 alert(rowID);

     if (!fancyConfirm(rowID, "Are you sure you want to delete this record?", function(ret) { alert(rowID) })) 
          e.preventDefault();

     });
```

You can see the actual page at http://www(@)fisheragservice(@)com/tm/users(@)html
Please replace the (@)'s with .'s because the page contans actual email addresses I rather not have a spma bot find..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just attach the `click` event on the link instead of the `img` inside it and then use `this`?

```
 $('#datatable tbody tr a.delete').live( 'click', function (e) {
 var rowID = $(this).attr('href');
 alert(rowID);

 if (!fancyConfirm(rowID, "Are you sure you want to delete this record?", function(ret) { alert(rowID) })) 
      e.preventDefault();

 });
```

[Example link](http://jsfiddle.net/ifaour/JHmC9/)

Comment: Thnks.. this one is a better way of doing what I need.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You care selecting all the anchors using $('a') to get the rowID. That will not work. Instead use the parent().attr() function in the click handler. i.e.:

```
$('#datatable tbody tr a.delete img').live( 'click', function (e) {
 var rowID = $(this).parent().attr('href');
 alert(rowID);

     if (!fancyConfirm(rowID, "Are you sure you want to delete this record?", function(ret) { alert(rowID) })) 
          e.preventDefault();

     });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if you are looking for the actual table row, or if the row
has some meaningful information like a database key.

if you indeed looking at a row id, consider the example below, which
uses the fnRender attribute.

```
var oTable = $('#inventory_list').dataTable ({
'bServerSide'    : true,
'bAutoWidth'     : false,
'bJQueryUI'      : false,
'sPaginationType': 'full_numbers',
'sAjaxSource'    : '/inventory/listall',
'aoColumns'      : 
[
{
  'bSearchable': false,
        "bSortable": false,
        "fnRender" : function ( oObj )
        {
          var colval = '<div class="editcol"><a href="/inventory/edit/'  +
                oObj.aData[0] + '">' + 
                '<img src="/img/edit.png" alt="edit"><a/>' +
                '<a href="/inventory/delete/' + oObj.aData[0] + '">' +
                '<img src="/img/delete.png" alt="delete"><a/>' +
                '</div>';

                return colval;
        }
},
null,
null,
null,
null,
null,
null,
null,
null,
null
]
});
```

The first column (out of 10) contains the edit/delete icons.

The listall call to the server return the inventory id in the first
cell, which is referenced by oObj.aData[0], ans used to build the URL.